# Python tksheet, how to change columns name

Tags: python

I want to create an app similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CzO0.png with tables and I want to make calculations with the numbers from tables.

Is there any way to change columns name? https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfVuf.png
And how to use numbers from table 1 and 2 and mace calculations and to put the results in the table3

```
from tkinter import *
import tksheet

root = Tk()
wrapper = Label(root, text='Seria 2')
wrapper.grid()
sheet1 = tksheet.Sheet(root, width=520, height=160, total_columns=4, total_rows=6, show_x_scrollbar=False, show_y_scrollbar=False)
sheet1.grid()
wrapper1 = Label(root, text='Seria 2')
wrapper1.grid()
sheet2 = tksheet.Sheet(root, width=520, height=160, total_columns=4, total_rows=6, show_x_scrollbar=False, show_y_scrollbar=False)
sheet2.grid()
wrapper2 = Label(root, text='Seria 2')
wrapper2.grid()
sheet3 = tksheet.Sheet(root, width=520, height=160, total_columns=4, total_rows=6, show_x_scrollbar=False, show_y_scrollbar=False)
sheet3.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The following shall work for your purpose:

```
sheet1.headers(["Caption colum 1","Caption colum 2","Caption colum 3","Caption colum 4"])
a = sheet1.get_cell_data(2, 1)                # row 2, column 1
b = sheet2.get_cell_data(0, 0)                # row 0, column 0
text = str(int(a) + int(b))                   # convert to int or whatever and back to string
sheet3.set_cell_data(0, 0, text, redraw=True) # row, line, value, refresh
```